# PID Control for a DC Motor : Reducing Settling Time

Tags: robotics, pid-controller

I want to control the velocity of a DC motor using PID.

In conventional PID Control, we have
u = kp * error + ki * integral_of_error + kd * derivative of error

In order to reduce settling time, I was thinking of writing instead,
u = kp * error + ki * integral_of_error + kd * derivative of error + f(desired_velocity)
, where the function f returns an approximation of the correct signal value.
f(x) = x/(max_velocity) might work.

I'm trying to avoid using a large ki, by reducing the initial error.

Is this a good idea?
Does it achieve anything or would good tuning get the same results?

In my case, the motor's behaviour should be relatively predictable. I don't expect the resistance to motion to vary drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Your additional term f(desired_velocity) is what we call feedforward gain. This is mostly used to achieve better tracking (smaller steady-state error), but it will also make the controller more robust.

In your case, I would try to increase the proportional gain kp as much as possible. Doing so you'll increase the bandwidth of your controller, and so decrease its settling time. Make sure that your system remains controllable (hence stable), and that there is no oscillatory response. The latter happens often when we increase the bandwidth as it also increases noise at the same time.